# Systematic TCP retransmission

Tags: tcp

I have 5 same devices connected to the switch. The IPs are constant. Using Wireshark I see a systematic TCP retransmissions within 1 or 2 usec on ports 1 and 5 (only). After swapping Port 1 with 2 for example the retransmission remains the same. It is probably not due to the lose data. What can be the issue?

Comment: Just to make sure, you're specifically talking about a _retransmission_ of a specific sequential packet? Also, are you getting the ACKs or not? If you do, then after you get the ACK, does it still re-send them?

Comment: you have too much traffic and are getting collisions?

Comment: Dear Yam. The retransmission happens for each packet that is sent to Port 1 and Port 5. Ports 2,3,4 are connected to similar devices and are working well. I'm getting the ACK for the first packet and Dup ACK for the retransmitted packet. The order is as follows: 1.Send, 2.Resend, 3.ACK, 4.Dup ACK.